# I am getting this error with asdf when running 'python' in my terminal on mac

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, asdf

I go to my terminal on my mac and run the 'python' command but receive the error:

```
/Users/mattlaszcz/.asdf/shims/python: line 3: 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf/0.11.0/libexec/bin/asdf: No such file or directory
/Users/mattlaszcz/.asdf/shims/python: line 3: exec: 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf/0.11.0/libexec/bin/asdf: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Why would I be missing this file or directory?

Comment: Just doing a cursory look of the text above, I noticed some instances where directory "asdf" has a period in front (aka, a hidden directory).  Are you mixing hidden and visible directories with basically the same name?

Comment: do you know how this could have happened? I did no manual manipulation of these directories only some installations with brew

Comment: I don't know how this might have happened.  You probably just need to backtrack the coding and testing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that could be a solution for that problem:

To fix simply edit /Users/me/.asdf/shims/elixir and change the /usr/local/libexec/private/asdf-exec to /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.6.2/libexec/private/asdf-exec.
I think it is caused because I had an old asdf 0.6.0 which was missing the .zshrc activation (source /usr/local/opt/asdf/asdf.sh).

Look here: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/418

Comment: is there a command to edit this? I have never done that before thanks!!